# How can I force parse.com to add an object as string instead of array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, parse-platform

When I add an NSString by using

```
[myObject addObject:myString forKey:myKey]
```

the string is converted to an array.

How can I force it to be a string? Should I create the rows of the table by hand using the data browser, or is there a way to do so by code (when creating the Class by objectWithClassName)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
[myObject setObject:myString forKey:myKey]
```

SETObject instead of ADDObject